# PHP DateTime Textual Representation

Tags: php, datetime

I wonder if it is possible to get this as an ouput using PHP DateTime:

'first thursday of February 2021'

The other way round were

```
$date = new DateTime('first thursday of February 2021');
```

What I have to accomplish: I have a given date and want to know, if it is the first thursday or not without building the date and comparing dates after this like:

```
$date = new DateTime('first thursday of February 2021');
$given_date = new DateTime('2021-02-04');
return ($given_date == $date);
```

Anyone?
I forgot: my given date can be the second saturday in march or the third friday in june and so on.

I will explain a little further for those who doesn't understand my question. Imaging a time table which says: all thursdays office is open from 8am to 5pm but first thursday in march office will open at 7am and closes at 6pm. Now a customer wants to schedule a meeting and we have only a date but must know: is it the first thursday or not. My database holds such information like day, month and possibly position in month. My solution now is a loop to determine the position in month.

```
private function getPositionInMonth(DateTime $date)
{
    $positions = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
    $day_name = $date->format('l');
    foreach ($positions as $i => $position) {
        $str = $position . ' ' . $day_name . ' ' . $date->format('F') . ' ' . $date->format('Y');
        $test_date = new DateTime($str);
        if ($test_date->format('d.m.Y') == $date->format('d.m.Y')) {
            return ($i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

All other information can be fetched in the sql query.

Comment: Another way to do so: https://3v4l.org/OBYZo

Comment: No, I don't believe it can be done without some custom code. The `format` method doesn't contain such logic.

Comment: Too bad it would be so comfortably

Comment: No, it would be quite nonsensical actually. Why should your scripting logic to determine whether some date is the 1st (, 2nd, 3rd, …) occurrence of that day in the month, rely on comparing _textual_ representations of that fact in a specific language? This should be solved using a tiny bit of _math_ instead.

Comment: He CBroe, you are right. It is bullshit to look for textual representation and furthermore the DateTime isn't working correct I think. Tested with 2021-05-08 which is the second saturday in may but DateTime gives for that the first saturday.

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime object should be formatted as a string like "first thursday of February 2021".

```
function formatNoWeekday(Datetime $date){
  $no = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth'];
  $day = $date->format('j');
  $frm = $date->format(' l \o\f F Y'); 
  foreach($no as $n){
    $strDate = $n.$frm;
    if(date_create($strDate)->format('j') == $day){
      return $strDate;
    }
  }
  return false; 
}

$result = formatNoWeekday(date_create('2021-02-16'));
//"third Tuesday of February 2021"
```

Comment: The question is about whether there's a built-in way of outputting `first thursday of February 2021` (literally) from a `DateTime` object.

Comment: Thank you @El_Vanja. I misunderstood the question. New trial.

Comment: See my question, I have added some explanations. It would be great if there were an inbuild function which returns 'second wednesday in march 2021' for a given date 2021-03-10

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a tiny bit of math like CBroe suggested:

```
private function getPositionInMonth(DateTime $date)
{
    $test_date = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-') . '01');
    $diff = round(($date->getTimestamp() -  $test_date->getTimestamp()) / 86400, 0);
    if($diff < 7) {
        return 1;
    }
    return (int)($diff / 7) + 1;
}
```

That function will give the position in month.

(Diff calculation fixed, DateTime gives d=0 and m=1 for the 29th of march, now it works. If you find any date which fails please mention it)

Comment: Check getPositionInMonth (new DateTime ('2021-03-29')); For the Timezone 'Europe/Berlin' I get 1 as the result.

Answer (score -1):

DateTime object supports relative formats. For this you can call method `modify`

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->modify('first thursday of February 2021');
$given_date = new DateTime('2021-02-04');

return ($given_date == $date);
```

[DateTime::modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

[Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. It is asking about the opposite - creating a date from values such as `2021-02-04 00:00:00` and then having the object print the interpretation such as `first thursday of February 2021`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: How do you think, now it's better?